# MySQL order by value in EAV table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I sort by value here? I need to get documents ID in order of a value, if present.

Example of result query:

```
+------+------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | name | wfid       | docid | created             | updated             |
+------+------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 5269 | DOC2 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:56 | 2014-02-25 09:39:51 |
| 5270 | DOC2 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:57 | 2014-02-25 10:41:57 |
| 5271 | DOC2 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:57 | 2014-02-25 10:42:20 |
+------+------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I don't know how to achieve it. It works with a very ugly query but with no capability of ordering. Example, I would like to have all documents that are from `Client1` and order it by `Period`. The user must have permission to see the document, permission are composed by `wfid`, `docid`, and `userid`.

Is it possible?

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b49e8

Schema:

```
mysql> describe documents;
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field   | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id      | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| name    | char(100) | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| wfid    | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| docid   | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| created | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| updated | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe users;
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| login    | char(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password | char(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe permissions;
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| wfId   | char(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| docId  | char(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userId | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe keywords;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| document_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| keyword     | char(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value       | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Data:

```
mysql> select * from permissions;
+----+------------+-------+--------+
| id | wfId       | docId | userId |
+----+------------+-------+--------+
| 13 | documentos | doc   |      7 |
+----+------------+-------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
+----+-------+----------+
| id | login | password |
+----+-------+----------+
|  7 | admin | a        |
+----+-------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from documents;
+------+------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | name | wfid       | docid | created             | updated             |
+------+------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 5263 | DOC1 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:44 | 2014-02-25 09:38:09 |
| 5264 | DOC1 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:50 | 2014-02-25 09:38:25 |
| 5265 | DOC1 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:50 | 2014-02-25 09:38:37 |
| 5266 | DOC1 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:50 | 2014-02-25 09:38:59 |
| 5267 | DOC1 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:51 | 2014-02-25 09:39:10 |
| 5268 | DOC2 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:56 | 2014-02-25 09:39:25 |
| 5269 | DOC2 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:56 | 2014-02-25 09:39:51 |
| 5270 | DOC2 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:57 | 2014-02-25 10:41:57 |
| 5271 | DOC2 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:57 | 2014-02-25 10:42:20 |
| 5272 | DOC2 | documentos | doc   | 2014-02-25 09:34:58 | 2014-02-25 10:43:04 |
+------+------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from keywords;
+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| id    | document_id | keyword   | value    |
+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 15888 |        5263 | Nombre    | Cliente1 |
| 15889 |        5264 | Nombre    | Cliente1 |
| 15890 |        5265 | Nombre    | Cliente1 |
| 15891 |        5266 | Nombre    | Cliente2 |
| 15892 |        5267 | Nombre    | Cliente3 |
| 15893 |        5268 | Nombre    | Cliente3 |
| 15894 |        5269 | Nombre    | Cliente3 |
| 15895 |        5270 | Nombre    | Cliente4 |
| 15896 |        5271 | Nombre    | Cliente4 |
| 15897 |        5272 | Nombre    | Cliente4 |
| 15898 |        5263 | Periodo   | 201301   |
| 15899 |        5263 | OtroValor | 1        |
| 15900 |        5264 | Periodo   | 201301   |
| 15901 |        5264 | OtroValor | 1        |
| 15902 |        5265 | Periodo   | 201301   |
| 15903 |        5265 | OtroValor | 1        |
| 15904 |        5266 | Periodo   | 201302   |
| 15905 |        5266 | OtroValor | 2        |
| 15906 |        5267 | Periodo   | 201302   |
| 15907 |        5267 | OtroValor | 2        |
| 15908 |        5268 | Periodo   | 201302   |
| 15909 |        5268 | OtroValor | 2        |
| 15910 |        5269 | Periodo   | 201303   |
| 15911 |        5269 | OtroValor | 3        |
| 15912 |        5270 | Periodo   | 201303   |
| 15913 |        5270 | OtroValor | 3        |
| 15914 |        5271 | Periodo   | 201304   |
| 15915 |        5271 | OtroValor | 3        |
| 15916 |        5272 | Periodo   | 201304   |
+-------+-------------+-----------+----------+
29 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b49e8

Comment: Does it help if we start with something like this... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b49e8/1 ... ?

Comment: ...or, more completely... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b49e8/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I did the trick, so there we go:

First, you must INNER JOIN `docs` and `permissions` table on the conditions you want (same docid and same wfid), to get only rows from `docs` that have permissions. And then, you filter by user to get only the user you want. I put the condition at the end, but you may include in the ON condition if you wish it, to improve performance if you're joining the table later. After that, you put the order condition you want.

The SQL I ended up with is:

```
SELECT  d.id, d.name, d.wfid, d.docid, d.created, d.updated 
FROM documents d
INNER JOIN permissions p
ON (d.wfid = p.wfId
    AND d.docid = p.docId)
WHERE p.userid = 7
ORDER BY d.created DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b49e8/14/0

It could be nice if you included an index for `created`, `wfid` and `docid` fields in `docs` to improve performance, as you use them as a key in the inner join and for ordering.

UPDATE

Check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b49e8/19/0

I've added the other tables to the query, making twice the join over keywords:

```
SELECT  d.id, d.name, d.wfid, d.docid, d.created, d.updated, k1.keyword
FROM documents d
INNER JOIN permissions p
ON (d.wfid = p.wfId
    AND d.docid = p.docId)
INNER JOIN keywords k1
ON (k1.document_id = d.id
   AND k1.keyword = 'Periodo' )

INNER JOIN keywords k2
ON (k2.document_id = d.id
   AND k2.keyword = 'Nombre' )

WHERE p.userid = 7
AND k2.value = 'Cliente1'

ORDER BY d.created DESC
```

As you can see, I added the keyword joined to show it's "Periodo"

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, what I need is to order by a value in the `keywords` table, here you are using the `documents` table for order.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read it in the question. Please, update it because you don't say anything about keywords and how it's related with the other tables. If you want that table for ordering, you must join to the query I wrote above.

Comment: Ok, I think it does now what you want, ;D

Comment: I think this does what I need: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b49e8/24 thanks a lot I will start from there

Comment: I see I am able to order by the `keyword value` that is on the `ON (k1.document_id = d.id
   AND k1.keyword = 'Periodo' )
`, is there a way I can ADD another keyword as column, like `OtroValor` to be able to order with this?

Comment: Never mind I've figured out thanks to the `INNER JOIN keywords k(subn)`